# Adding luxon to NetSuite using SuiteScript

Tags: momentjs, netsuite, suitescript, luxon

I need to work with some dates in a script and I've used luxon (momentjs) before in my other projects. I've added the AMD file (https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/install?id=amd-systemjs-requirejs-etc) to File Cabinet (/SuiteScripts/luxon/min.js). I'm attempting to add it to the define method in my js file:

```
define(['N/https', ..., 'N/log', { 'paths': { 'luxon': '/SuiteScripts/luxon'} }],
    function callbackFunction(https, ..., log, luxon) {
```

I don't get any errors doing this but when I call `var DateTime = luxon.DateTime` I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "DateTime" from undefined" along with the location of that variable.

What's the correct way to include the luxon or similar added js file?

Answer (score 0):

If calling luxon in a client script, you do not need to declare the callback.

I've successfully used luxon using this method. I declare it before the functions so I don't need to declare it everytime.

I've not yet worked out how to use it in Server side scripts.

Note, I used the basic version
https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.js

```
define(['N/https', ..., 'N/log', './luxon'],

    function callbackFunction(https, ..., log) {

        var DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
        var Duration = luxon.Duration;

        function pageInit(ctx) {
            var now = Datetime.now()
        }

    etc....
}

return {pageInit:pageInit}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple naming issue.
You wrote:

> to File Cabinet (/SuiteScripts/luxon/min.js)

but your script tries to add luxon(and assumes the `.js`)

change your code to:

```js
define(['N/https', ..., 'N/log', '/SuiteScripts/luxon/min'],
    function callbackFunction(https, ..., log, luxon) {
```